# Dynamic Memory Allocation - When and Why

Tags: c

I am a novice in C and trying to understand basic concepts in C, Like when and Why I have to allocate Memory for a string pointer.
here I have a sample program. I have commented in appropriate locations. Please help me understand.

```
/ Please help me understand why do I have allocate Memory in Case 2 while I don't have to in Case 1.

#include<stdio.h>
void xcopy(char *t,const char *s);
int  main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char name1[]="Asfakul";
  char *name;
  char *target;
  name=name1; // Here I dont have to allocate Memory (Case 1)
  puts(name);

  target=(char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));  // Here I have to allocate Memory (Case 2)
  xcopy(target,name);
  return 0;
}


void xcopy(char *t,const char *s)
{
  while( *s !='\0')
  {
    *t=*s;
    t++;
    s++;

  }
  puts(t);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you start with `name1`, which is an array of `char`.  Then  you take `name`, which is a `char *`, and assign `name1` to it.  Since `name1` is being evaluated in pointer context, it refers to a pointer to the first element of the array.  So now `name` points to the first element of `name1`.

In the second case, `target` is assigned a memory location returned by a call to `calloc`, which in this case is a block of 10 bytes.  The bytes now pointed to by `target` can now be used.

As with any pointer, you need to assign it a value before you can dereference it.  That value can be either the address of some other variable, or a block of memory returned by the `malloc` family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
name=name1; // Here I dont have to allocate Memory (Case 1)
```

In this case , you ***don't allocate memory to*** `name` , *you just make it point to array* `name1` . In short , `name` now has address of first element of array `name1`.

```
target=(char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));  // Here I have to allocate Memory (Case 2)
xcopy(target,name);
```

And in case `2`  you need to allocate memory as you copy the contents of `name1` at the memory block to which `target` points to .

Here , it is needed as if you don't allocate memory then `target` point to anything (*maybe garbage*) and writing to that location will cause *undefined behaviour*.

**Note** - You don't need to `free` any memory in case `1` as pointer points to a array on stack . But you need to do `free(target);` in case `2` as you allocate memory on heap.